# Authentication failure when starting OpenVAS scan

Tags: authentication, openvas

I am running OpenVAS 9 on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. After installation, using the GUI, OpenVAS works fine, no problems with logging in nor starting scans. The problem however is that when I try to start scans via script of [mgeeky](https://gist.github.com/mgeeky/a038f809dff4d308db94f5f657908da7) I get an **error** stating that the **`authentication failed`**. The error is confirmed by `openvasmd.log` where I can see the following message"

```
omp:WARNING:2018-06-15 12h58.08 utc:3603: Authentication failure for 'admin' from <IP_ADDRESS_SERVER>
```

I tried to rebuild and update the database in the hopes of that having an effect, but, alas. Also, I created a new account to see if authentication would work but got the same result as with the admin account.

Earlier this week I installed another system in a similar fashion and haven't had any issues with that system. The only difference between these two system (that I could find) s is that the previous one is VM on my own system. The current (not functioning) one has been imported in a vSphere environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why I constantly got the response that the authentication failed. In [mgeeky's](https://gist.github.com/mgeeky/a038f809dff4d308db94f5f657908da7) script, on line 200, the **'$PASS'** parameter contains apostrophes 
.

`out=$(omp -u $USER -w '$PASS' -h $HOST -p $PORT --xml=\`

Removing the apostrophes results in the authentication process successfully completing.

This solution worked for me, hopefully more people can benefit from it.